# Is Scala Option the same as a C# Nullable type?

Tags: c#, scala

In Scala you have `Option[Int]` which will be `Some(number)` or `None` and has a property `isDefined` which returns `true` in the first case and `false` in the other.

In C# you have `int?` which will be `a number` or `null` and has a property `HasValue` which returns `true` in the first case and `false` in the other.

Is Scala's `Option` the same as a C#'s `Nullable type` and are there any differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't at all the same. In addition to other answers:

1. Scala has `Option[Option[Int]]`; C# doesn't have `int??`.
2. Scala has `Option[String]`; C# doesn't have `string?`.
3. In C#, there is an implicit conversion from `T` to `T?`; in Scala, there is no implicit conversion from `T` to `Option[T]` (Scala allows you to define such a conversion manually, but this isn't recommended).

This means `Option` is a lot more *uniform* and *composable* than `?` and allows it to be used much more widely. E.g. Scala's `Map[K, V].get(K)` returns `Option[V]`; but in .Net, [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>[TKey]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) can't return `TValue?`, because `TValue` can be a reference type. Even an equivalent of `Option.map` would need to have separate implementations for functions returning value types and reference types.

I'd also like to reiterate that `get` should be avoided! `isDefined` when not followed by `get` is perfectly fine, though.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, fixed.

Comment: `Even an equivalent of Option.map would need to have separate implementations for functions returning value types and reference types.`  Actually in C# the method is baked into the language using the `.?` operator.  It supports all nullable types, including `Nullable`.

Comment: No, `.?` is not an equivalent of `map`, because you can't pass an arbitrary delegate to it. And if it were, it would have to be built into language, you couldn't write your own (as far as I understand).

Comment: In a sense you can.  It's not strictly equivalent, but it accomplishes the same purpose, and neither is capable of doing anything the other isn't, it'd just be written out slightly differently.  It's the same conceptual operation though.

Comment: Writing your own version of `Map` for `Nullable` wouldn't be hard at all.  `public static Nullable<TResult> Map<TSource, TResult>(this Nullable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector) where TSource : struct where TResult : struct { if (source.HasValue) return selector(source.Value); else return null; }`  If `Nullable<T>` allowed `T` to be a reference type or `Nullable` it'd be able to be one implementation.  So at most it's just a colliery of your first point.

Comment: I was going to ask how you can use `.?` to write an equivalent to `.map(x => x + 1)` (which would return `null` on `null`, return `x + 1` on non-null `x`), but figured out you can use it with extension methods. I'll have to fall back to the second sentence of my previous comment :) (There is also non-equivalence in case member or extension method itself is/returns `null`.)

Comment: It's intended to be an _example_ of consequences of the first two points.

Comment: All operators are lifted to support nullable values, so `x + 1` already has exactly the semantics that `map` would provide, namely that the whole expression is `null` if any of the nullable input values are null.

Comment: Ah, I see. But it turns out comparison has quite different semantics: `x < 1` is false for null `x`, not `null` (presumably for similarity to SQL). Which gets back to the uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

C#'s `Nullable type` is meant to allow value types to have `null` values while Scala's `Option` is meant to get rid of `null` entirely. Instead, you pattern match on `Option[A]` to get a `Some` or a `None`. You can think of `Option` as a generalized version of `Nullable type`.

However, the problems dealt with aren't exactly the same: C# is trying to add object-like behavior to value types while Scala is trying to provide a safe alternative to `null`. However, Scala's `Option` does also sort of solve the value type problem `Nullable type` was designed for:

```
scala> case class MyInt(val i: Int) extends AnyVal // scala value type

scala> null : MyInt
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Null(null)
  required: MyInt
        null : MyInt
        ^

scala> None : Option[MyInt]
res1: Option[MyInt] = None

scala> Some(MyInt(1)) : Option[MyInt]
res2: Option[MyInt] = Some(MyInt(1))
```

I should also mention that `Nullable type` is built into the C# language, while `Option` is just a regular Scala class in the standard library.